# how to get points in distance from point

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2

first what I want to achive, than I think I can do it

I want to find streets on the edge of area where center point is point where I am standing.

Now for example I'm selecting area with 2km radius. I want to find 360 points (1 point for each degree) and check if point with this coordinates is street or not. Now 3 questions

1. How to get each point in distance from me
2. How to get latitude and longitude of this point
3. How to check if this point is street or not

Answer (score 0):

> How to get each point in distance from me

Having the Lat and Lng of source and destination points, you can use `Location.distanceBetween` method.

```
float[] results = new float[3];
Location.distanceBetween(srcLat, srcLng, destLat, destLng, results);
```

The distance between the two points is in `index 0` : `results[0]`

> How to get latitude and longitude of this point

Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14332348/android-find-latitude-longitude-of-x-point-from-defined-location)

> How to check if this point is street or not

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9409195/how-to-get-complete-address-from-latitude-and-longitude) is another link.

Hope this help.

Comment: so if I understand you I first need to get lat and lon of point on the edge of area and than check if it is street or not. Is that correct ?