# How do I make a specific route and trace it by calculating length with Google Maps API

Tags: android, swift, google-maps, maps

Has been searching and wondering if I can develop this function with Google Maps API.

Basically I wanna do is

1. Have a fixed route on Google Map
2. Calculate the length of that route
3. Based on a number of some lengths, and show where it's located on the route.

I'm reading the documents, but can't find the API for them.

[image]

Thank you for your attention and help.

Comment: I question seems to be really broad. You can indeed use Directions API to get the route and show it on map, also you can show markers at certain position of the route. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/47556917/5140781 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/48891622/5140781.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I'll try to make it clearer next time. Thanks anyway.